# Error 438 when aligning a table's column in Excel generated Word doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, alignment

I've spent a bunch of time trying to figure out how to get this done but to no avail.

We populate a new word doc based on a template using data from Excel. Excel VBA script gets the data and pastes it into the Word doc at the indicated bookmarks. This works great.

However, when I try to align a column that already exists in the table, it throws an error. I've tried other variants but am just shooting in the dark.

The code compiles without error.

```
' This code runs fine
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).PreferredWidth = 100

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Select

' I get an error "438 - Object Doesn't support this property or method"
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim c As Cell, t as Table
Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(1) 
With t.Columns(2) 
    For Each c In .Cells 
        c.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 
    Next c 
End With
```

Comment: Solved my challenge perfectly. I was hoping for a column-wise solution but if I have to do it cell-by-cell, so be it.